# Extract YouTube Video Link Using YouTube API

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api

I have developed an app that loads a user's videos and when they click on the cell in the tableview it goes to another viewcontroller that holds a bunch of different information.

I'm trying to extract the actual YouTube link from a specific video. I print out the links I get and they come in this form.

**https://www.youtube.com/v/Xf5pXlZJr1U?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata**

But I want it to be in this form.

**http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xf5pXlZJr1U**

Reason being that I want people to share the link via social media, but it comes out weird when it's in the first format.

Is there any way to easily convert the links?

---

SAMPLE CODE AND ANSWER EDIT

```
GDataEntryBase *entry2 = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [[entry2 title] stringValue];
NSArray *contents = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaContents];
GDataMediaContent *flashContent = [GDataUtilities firstObjectFromArray:contents withValue:@"application/x-shockwave-flash" forKeyPath:@"type"];
NSString *tempURL = [flashContent URLString];

NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString]]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry2 mediaGroup];
GDataMediaDescription *desc2 = [mediaGroup mediaDescription];
NSString *mystring = [desc2 stringValue];

NSArray *listItems = [tempURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *NewURL = @"";

NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:[listItems objectAtIndex:0]];
NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:@"//"];
NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:[listItems objectAtIndex:2]];
NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:@"watch"];
NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:@"?v="];

NSArray *listItems2 = [[listItems objectAtIndex:4] componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];    
NewURL = [NewURL stringByAppendingString:[listItems2 objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: add some code and the youtube api you use

Comment: There you go. I gave some code.

Comment: api??please include api

Comment: I used the standard GData Api that you can download off of google's site.

Comment: its better you add it in question.
Nobody is gonna search and find an api for answering

Comment: The API is over 30 classes.

Comment: just log the  [thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString] and include it in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) docs then you will find number of useful methods for yourself to use, e.g **`componentsSeparatedByString`**  splitting the string in two different chunks depending on some particular character &  **`stringByAppendingString`** for appending string to an existing string. It is not difficult to use these methods, just use according to your needs.